# How to select a dropdown control in an ASP.NET repeater through jQuery/javascript?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET Repeater control with a dropdown (with values 1, 2, 3 ) and a textbox. Thus, multiple Instances of code are generated/created in each ItemTemplate with a dropdown and a text box.

I am trying to create a function in jQuery/javascript, where whenever the value in the dropdown is selected to be 1, textbox should be get disabled. Now this dropdown can be anyone say first, 3rd, or 5th.. and repective textbox should get disabled.

Could anyone kindly guide me in being able to make this work for each row in the Repeater?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.dropdown').change(function()
{
   //include condition to determine "if dropdown is selected to be 1"

   var $row = $(this).parents('tr:first'); //find the row in which this dropdown is
   if($(this).val() == 1)
   {

     $row.find('.textbox:first').attr('disabled','disabled');​​​​​​ //assuming you put a class on your textbox
     //$row.find('.textbox:first').attr('disabled','true');​​​​​​
     //$row.find('.textbox:first').prop('disabled','true');​​​​​​
   }
   else
       $row.find('.textbox:first').attr('enabled','true'); //assuming you put a class on your textbox
});
```

Comment: I tried this code, but it works only when we have just single repeater item, at the moment i add 2nd, it stops working. Also i don't have a class on my text box, don't we have any other way to access it?

Comment: `input[type=text]` like @Yograj posted in his answer. What does it take to add a class to your textbox? I do that to keep my jQuery simple

Comment: thanks very much, i don't want to do input[type = text] as in future one may add another text box in the repeater item, then both of these will get disable. Also as i mentioned I tried this code, but it works only when we have just single repeater item, at the moment i add 2nd, it stops working.

Comment: Debug, Check your browser console for errors, put an alert in the function to output `$(this)` and don't forget to wrap everything in `$(document).ready()`

Comment: If you had pasted your markup (esp. when you have 2 repeater items) as suggested, it would have been easier to help

Answer (score 0):

If your repeater render as table. then you can try.

```
$("select").change(function(){
    var _this = $(this); 
    var parentRow = _this.closest('tr');
    if(_this.val() == "1"){
        parentRow.find("input[type=text]").prop("disabled", true);
    }else {
        parentRow.find("input[type=text]").prop("disabled", false);
    }
});
```